# How to set environment variables in AWS EC2 from Azure Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, azure-devops

I'm trying to deploy Django on AWS EC2 with AzureDevops pipeline. I have a ssh task to run docker container and I would like to set environment variables. I have tried various commands, but I can't get it.

Here's the task:

```
- task: SSH@0
  displayName: Restart Docker Container
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: "TMC AWS EC2 Stage Authentication"
    runOptions: "inline"
    inline: |
      echo $(DEBUG)
      echo $(export DEBUG=$(DEBUG))
      ...
      sudo docker stop $(containerName)
      sudo docker rm $(containerName)
      sudo docker run -d -p 80:8000 --name $(containerName) $(AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY_NAME)/${{ parameters.imageName }}:${{ parameters.environment }}-latest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved passing environment variables file to docker run command.

```
- task: SSH@0
  displayName: Restart Docker Container
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: "TMC AWS EC2 Stage Authentication"
    runOptions: "inline"
    inline: |
      touch .env
      echo SECRET_KEY=$(SECRET_KEY) >> .env
      echo DEBUG=$(DEBUG) >> .env
      ...
      sudo docker stop $(containerName)
      sudo docker rm $(containerName)
      sudo docker run -d -p 80:8000 --env-file=.env --name $(containerName) $(AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY_NAME)/${{ parameters.imageName }}:${{ parameters.environment }}-latest
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/ssh-v0?view=azure-pipelines) you can pass arguments if you use 'script' as your runOptions.

```yaml
- task: SSH@0
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'TMC AWS EC2 Stage Authentication'
    runOptions: 'script'
    scriptPath: 'myscript.sh'
    args: '$(containerName)'
    readyTimeout: '20000'
```